# Chooser and launcher WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I wonder how can I launch an application just installed on my phone by clicking a button in my application. For example I want to launch "Fruit Ninja" by pressing `button1` in my "exampleapplication" and if the application is not installed, how can the button direct to the market install page automatically?

I used this method and its done, but it doesn't always have the market id.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
 marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "1example-dxxx-4xxe-afb7-1xxxtestx04 ";
 marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

One application can not currently launch another - this API doesn't currently exist in the SDK. I suggest going to http://wpdev.uservoice.com and requesting that feature be added in a future SDK.

Comment: her is a good way to get the market id  and by use it in the code above you got the way am talking about thank u all
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/find-id-of-windows-phone-7-app-and-create-direct-zune-marketplace-link/